# How to write this SQL Server syntax to update a column based on the values of 2 other columns in that same table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, case

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I need to write an SQL query that will update a column (called ToY) in my DateDimension Table.

Here is an extract of my DateDimension Table:

```
Day      Month     Year         Date          ToY
 1         11       2014     2014-11-01       NULL
 2         11       2014     2014-11-02       NULL
```

I need to update that ToY column based on this logic:

For all dates falling between November 2014 to October 2015, ToY will be 'ToY 14-15' and for all dates falling between November 2015 to October 2015, ToY will be 'ToY 15-16'.

eg:If Month = 11 and Year = 2014 Then ToY = 'ToY 14-15'

I have tried this piece of SQL code but it's not working:

```
 UPDATE DateDimension

 SET ToY = CASE Month+Year

 WHEN 112014 THEN 'ToY 14-15'

 ELSE ToY

 END
 GO
```

I did a search and found out that I could write that third line as:
    WHEN Month = 11 AND Year = 2014 THEN 'ToY 14-15'

But I'm stuck with what follows after the CASE statement:

```
Set ToY = CASE ??
```

Comment: And what to update for other values? can you please add some extra example?

Comment: "and so on." - you give us exactly one example and expect us to discern a pattern based on it?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I have edited my question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses a few functions but hopefully makes my thinking quite clear:

```
UPDATE DateDimension

SET ToY = 'ToY ' + 
    CONVERT(char(2),DATEADD(month,-10,[Date]),12) + '-' +
    CONVERT(char(2),DATEADD(month,2,[Date]),12)
```

`DATEADD(month,-10,...` - for any date earlier than November, move this date into last year. `DATEADD(month,2,...` - for any date later than October, move this date into next year. Taken together, these either select last year and this year (for earlier than November) or this year and next year.

`CONVERT(char(2),<date>,12)` - convert a date to a string, in the [style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187928.aspx) `yymmdd` - but because I've asked for a `char(2)`, only the first 2 characters are retained.

Comment: Fantastic! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

You can have boolean expressions in the case, so:

```
update DateDimension
set ToY = case when month = 11 and year = 2014 then 'ToY 14-15' 
          else ToY end
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic for getting "14-15" from 2014-11 isn't clear.  Perhaps you are adding "4" to each month.

In any case, this gives the idea for how to do an update based on the `year` and `month` columns:

```
update DateDimension
    set ToY = 'ToY ' + right('00' + cast(year as varchar(255)), 2) + '-' +
              right('00' + cast(month + 4 as varchar(255)), 2);
```

Comment: I have edited my question to make the logic more clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE DateDimension
SET ToY = 
  CASE WHEN Month >= 11 then 
    'ToY '+cast( right(year,2) as varchar(2))+'-'+cast(right(year,2)+1 as varchar(2))
   WHEN Month < 11 then 
    'ToY '+cast( right(year,2)-1 as varchar(2))+'-'+cast(right(year,2) as varchar(2))

  ELSE ToY
  END
```

Assuming Year is numeric value, if the Year is string use substring.